# Flutter, firebase and Hive causing error on initializing Hive. What is the solution?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, hive

The error MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider))

The code

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Hive.initFlutter("hive_boxes");

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  GetIt.instance.registerSingleton<FirebaseService>(
    FirebaseService(),
  );

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `flutter clean` & then compile the app again? I have gotten this error with google_fonts package but it should fix it in your case as well.